# How to handle to imported classes in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have a package with the following abbreviated directory structure:

```
package/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
    docs/
        source/
            a.rst
            b.rst
```

`__init__.py` contains:

```
from .a import A
from .b import B
```

a.py contains

```
from .b import B
```

I am using "show-inheritance" in the rst

All the functionality and tests work perfectly, but I get an error message when I run "make html" in \docs

```
"..../a.py", line x in <module>
    from .b import B
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I think it is related to paths and directories but I cannot see how the issue can be resolved

Comment: `package` needs to be importable.  You could extend `sys.path` in the Sphinx config relative to that config module (`__file__` and `os.path` functions are useful here).

Comment: Thanks. The directory containing the modules already appears in sys.path

Comment: It shoudn't! The directory containing the _package_, and only that should. If the modules directory(s) are also in `sys.path` you suddenly have more than one way to import modules which may/will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

In `a.py` try:

```
from package.b import B
```

Your `__init.py__` binds the name `package` to the submodule `b`.  Details in [import submodules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules).

Comment: Thanks. But that just gives me ImportError: No module named package.b